# How to clear records of Shared Data Extension using WSproxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, wsproxy

I am using the below script for a particular testing scenario to clear ALL [x] or a specific [y]
Data extension. However, I am unable to use this script to CLEAR records of Shared Data extension :(

I even tried to internationalization using MID but did not work.

```js
<script runat="server">
    /* parameter -->   ?x=true                   || will clear ALL DataExtensions        */
    /* parameter -->   ?y=_YourDEcustomerKey_    || will clear specific DataExtension    */
    
    Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");
try{  
    
    var x = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("x");
    var y = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("y");
    
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();   
   // prox.setClientId({ "ID": 'xxxxx', "UserID": 'Xxxx' }); setting this did not work
    var action = "ClearData";
    var opts = {};
  
  
    if (y)
    {
       var CustomerKey = y;
       var props = { CustomerKey: CustomerKey};
       var data = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props, action, opts);
      Write("<br>result: " + Stringify(data));
    }
  
  
   if (x == "true")
       {
         
    var CustomerKey1 = "MyDE1";
    var CustomerKey2 = "MyDE2";
    var CustomerKey3 = "MyDE3";
    var CustomerKey4 = "MyDE4";
    var CustomerKey5 = "MyDE5";
    var CustomerKey6 = "MyDE6";
    var CustomerKey7 = "MyDE7";
    var CustomerKey8 = "MyDE8";
    var CustomerKey9 = "MyDE9";
    var CustomerKey10 = "MyDE10";

    var props1 = { CustomerKey: CustomerKey1};
    var props2 = { CustomerKey: CustomerKey2};
    var props3 = { CustomerKey: CustomerKey3};
    var props4 = { CustomerKey: CustomerKey4};
    var props5 = { CustomerKey: CustomerKey5};
    var props6 = { CustomerKey: CustomerKey6};
    var props7 = { CustomerKey: CustomerKey7};
    var props8 = { CustomerKey: CustomerKey8};
    var props9 = { CustomerKey: CustomerKey9};
    var props10 = { CustomerKey: CustomerKey10};
           
         
       }
  else
  {
    Write('Please pass secrete parameter x to clear all or y with key');
  }
    
    if (x == "true")
       {
         
         var data1 = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props1, action, opts);
         var data2 = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props2, action, opts);
         var data3 = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props3, action, opts);
         var data4 = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props4, action, opts);
         var data5 = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props5, action, opts);
         var data6 = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props6, action, opts);
         var data7 = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props7, action, opts);
         var data8 = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props8, action, opts);
         var data9 = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props9, action, opts);
         var data10 = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props10, action, opts);
         
       }
  else
  {
    Write('Please pass secrete parameter x to clear all or y with key');
  }

  Write("<br>result1: " + Stringify(data1));
  Write("<br>result2: " + Stringify(data2));
  Write("<br>result3: " + Stringify(data3));
  Write("<br>result4: " + Stringify(data4));
  Write("<br>result5: " + Stringify(data5));
  Write("<br>result6: " + Stringify(data6));
  Write("<br>result7: " + Stringify(data7));
  Write("<br>result8: " + Stringify(data8));
  Write("<br>result9: " + Stringify(data9));
  Write("<br>result10: " + Stringify(data10));
 
  
  } catch(Error) { Write(Stringify(Error)); }
</script>
```

> > Please feel free to suggest if any other ways to clear a shared data extension(s) using SSJS or WSproxy.

Comment: Are you doing this from a child or parent BU? I don’t think it’s possible to do it from a child..

Comment: Thanks for checking @zuzannamj... here is the architecture.... we have `A_BU` Grand Parent... `B_Bu` child of `A_BU` ... `C_BU` child of `B_BU`.... the DE are located in a Shared folder shared between `B_BU` and `C_BU` .... and also the cloud page with above code is located in `B_BU`

Comment: I’d make sure you’re using the `ent.` prefix and I’d also try running this script from the grand parent BU

Comment: @VishalKumarCV Is it okay to use SQL? Though I think SQL may not work with dynamic [y] DE

Comment: Thank you soo much @zuzannamj :) ... I just moved the script to GrandParent and it worked... however it was not working when I added ENT.MyDeCustkey, but worked with ENT ... this is strange!